# Creating a highly customized BarChart

Tags: graphics, customization, charts

I am trying to create a `BarChart` visualization for multi-step data filtering. Think of a traditional sales funnel: many leads, fewer prospects, few customers, very few return customers. The only kicker is, I want to show the percentage of data being lost by using Percentile layout for the `BarChart`, and I want to show that the slice of previous bar is the entirety of the content of the next bar using lines similar to Joined option, and if possible, fill the joining lines with color similar to the one used for selection.
Lastly,for my data content, there are 2 types of filters: binary (e.g. lead becomes prospect or not) and slice-of-pie (e.g. customers who spent between `X` and `Y`, where the slice would appear in the middle of the column, with rest of sales with lower amount appearing below, and higher amount appearing above). I can draw this using `Graphics` and basic primitives, but was really hoping that there's a clever way to adapt `BarChart`, so that I could use the built-in labeling or legending features, as well as the vertical axis. Or even go from `Percentile` to `Stacked`, as needed.

Here's a simple drawing of what I envision this could look like:
[image: Example of funnel barchart]

And if anyone can suggest an alternate visualization which will serve the purpose, I'd really appreciate it. I thought of using `TreeGraph` with `VertexSize` option, but it's less than trivial to visualize not only what made it into the filter, but also how much are you losing and where the loss occurs.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Verbeia's clever solution, and a little bit of additional engineering, this is what I came up with. Clearly there's endless room for improvement, but the automation works great.

```
data = {{4, 3, 4.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 6, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}};
lines = Flatten[Table[{
     {{1.501 n, 
       100 data[[n, 3 n - 2]]/Total@data[[n]]}, {1.5 n + .499, 
       0}}, {{1.501 n, 
       100 (data[[n, 3 n - 2]] + data[[n, 3 n - 1]])/
        Total@data[[n]]}, {1.5 n + .499, 100}}}
    , {n, 1, 3}], 1];

Show[
  BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
   BarSpacing -> {None, .5}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel"],
  ListLinePlot[lines, 
   Filling -> 
    Table[(2 n - 1) -> {{2 n}, 
       Directive[Opacity@0.75, 
        ColorData["Pastel"][(3 n - 2)/(3 4)]]}, {n, 1, 3}], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]]
  , ImageSize -> 850]
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in `Joined` option to `BarChart` doesn't really do what you want. So what I'd suggest is overlaying a `BarChart` on a `ListLinePlot` that creates the lines. Here is a simplified two-stacks-of-bars version.

```
data = {{4, 3, 0, 0, 4.5}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 0}};
```

The first point is that you will need to have zero-value elements in the bar chart data to ensure you get different coloring in the different stacks, or else use `Style` explicitly to customise the coloring in each stack.

Then you need to come up with lines that draw between the bars. This might be able to be automated, but it would require knowledge of which bar segments are the ones that "expand" to the next stack, as well as the `BarSpacing` option value in the `BarChart`, which determines the horizontal coordinates of the bars.

```
lines = {{{1, 100 data[[1, 1]]/Total[data[[1]] ]}, {1.5, 
 100 data[[1, 1]]/Total[data[[1]] ]}, {1.7, 0}}, 
{{1, 100 (data[[1, 1]] + data[[1, 2]])/Total[data[[1]] ]}, 
{1.5, 100 (data[[1, 1]] + data[[1, 2]])/Total[data[[1]] ]}, {1.7,  100}}};
```

Putting them together is fairly straightforward, but watch the `PlotRange` and `Filling` options in the `ListLinePlot` function:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[lines, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 101}}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}],
 BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Maybe with `PlotStyle -> None` in `ListLinePlot[ ]`.

Comment: Or `PlotStyle -> Dashed` in `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Or even using arrows instead of lines: `data = {{4, 3, 0, 0, 4.5}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 0}};
arrows = {Dashed, 
   Arrow[{{1.5, 100 data[[1, 1]]/Total[data[[1]]]}, {1.7, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{1.5, 
      100 (data[[1, 1]] + data[[1, 2]])/Total[data[[1]]]}, {1.7, 
      100}}]};

Show[BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"], Graphics[arrows,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 101}}]]`

Comment: @Verbeia: clever use of 0s in the BarChart, to hide slices of color!!! Very nice! Issue that I have with your solution, and perhaps you can enlighten me... your 1.5 number is hard-coded. As I add a custom number of bars to the plot, or as BarChart options change, I really don't know what that distance between bars will be. I can have anywhere from 1 bar (no lines) to a dozen bars or more (rare), with 4-6 bars being a very common scenario.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually see that any number of columns is created using the same spacing: 0.5 + (1+0.2)x#bars. I can now create a function to convert a list of any number of filters (2 or 3 elements) into lines and bars. and if I stack their order: {1,2,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,3,4,5,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,6,7}, I can apply any number of colors I want. Same with the lines, if I make them all separate lines, I can control colors with FillingStyle. WIN! Thank you!

Comment: @GregoryKlopper - I can't respond in detail until this evening (9am here). The [`BarSpacing` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarSpacing.html) says that for `BarChart`, the spacing is in fractions of widths of a bar; the bars are 1 in width and the first one is centred on 1. That means that the first bar's right edge will always be at 1.5, but the left edge of the next bar depends on `OptionValue[BarSpacing]`. I think it should be possible to automate your problem but it would be quite a bit of work. Let me think about it for a bit.

Comment: Note: reversing the order inside the Show, and only adding the lines that slant, not the horizontal slice, allowed be to keep the BarChart axes and labels.

Comment: @GregoryKlopper - yes I did it that way to illustrate the relationship between the coordinates. Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 9):

A custom `BarChart` that takes as input a dataset accepted by `BarChart` and the index of the element in each group that fans out to the next group:

```
ClearAll[ceF, funnelBarChart]
ceF[cedf_: "GlassRectangle", o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{color = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"], 
  spacing = If[#3 === {}, 0, #3[[1, 2]]],
  next = If[#3 === {}, 0, If[#3[[1, 3]] === "Percentile", 100, 
   If[Head[#3[[1, 1, 1]]] === Style, Total[#3[[1, 1]][[All, 1]]], Total[#3[[1, 1]]]] ]]},
 {ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][##], 
    Lighter@Lighter@color, EdgeForm[{Darker@color, Dashed}], 
    If[#3 === {}, {}, Polygon[{{#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 1]]}, {#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]}, 
    {#[[1, 2]] + spacing, next}, {#[[1, 2]] + spacing, 0}}]]}] &

funnelBarChart[data_, pieces_, layout_: "Stacked", spacing_: .5, 
  cef_: (ceF[])][o : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{d2 = data}, 
  Table[d2[[i, pieces[[i]]]] = (data[[i, pieces[[i]]]] -> {data[[i + 1]], 
       spacing, layout}), {i, Length[data] - 1}];
  BarChart[d2, Frame -> True, ChartLayout -> layout, 
   BarSpacing -> {0, spacing}, ChartElementFunction -> cef, o, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 25]]
```

**Examples:**

```
data = {{4, 2, 3, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, Range[4, 6]}

Row[funnelBarChart[data, {#, 2}][ColorFunction -> "Pastel"] & /@ {2, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Row[funnelBarChart[data, {#, 2}, "Percentile"][ColorFunction -> "Pastel"] & /@ {4, 3}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
data2 = Style[#, Hue[RandomReal[]]] & /@ # & /@ data;
Row[funnelBarChart[data2, {#, 2}][] & /@ {2, 3}]
```

[image]

```
i = 1; 
data3 = Map[Style[#, ColorData[60, "ColorList"][[i++]]] &, data, {-1}];
Row[funnelBarChart[data3, {#, 2}][] & /@ {2, 3}]
```

[image]